# How to reduce the memory of bitmapdrawable in Android 4.0?

Tags: android, memory, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have an image existed in device sdcard.

The path is /mnt/sdcard/001.jpg

Here is my activity

```
public class BitmapMemoryTestActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageView imv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imv);
    imv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/001.jpg"));
}
}
```

Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imv" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I test this project on Android 3.0 and Android 4.0 and dump the hprof.

The bitmapdrawable memory in the ImageView on Android 4.0 is bigger than 3.0

Android 3.0 retains heap is 3,692,864 byte
Android 4.0 retains heap is 7,385,320 byte

How to solve this problem?

P.S I don't want to down sample the image.

Comment: I guess the default config on Android 4.0 is Config.ARGB_8888, so it retains heap is double of Android 3.0. Now I set the config to Config.RGB_565, and it works for me. :)